# Is it possible to use IMPORTHTML to return only certain cells?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, importhtml

I'm currently using `IMPORTHTML` to import tables from a website that have five columns and three rows.  But, I only need three cells from each of these tables.  Is there a way to import just these three cells into my spreadsheet, rather than the entire table?

I could use `INDEX(IMPORTHTML`, but due to the number of `IMPORHTML` functions my spreadsheet is using, I fear it would slow it down even further than it already is if I triple that amount.

Comment: You're asking which cells in the table that I want?  The cells are R2C4, R2C5, and R3C1 before importing.

Answer (score 4):

pretty much possible:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://geizhals.de/?fs="&A1&"&in=";"table";0);2;3)
```

this one shall search for a phrase located in cell A1 and it will return data from a table 0, but only from a row 2 of that table and from a cell 3 of that row. in your case:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("siteurl";"TABLE";number);rownumber;cellnumber)
_________________________________________________________________

=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("siteurl";"TABLE";number);2;4)
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("siteurl";"TABLE";number);2;5)
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("siteurl";"TABLE";number);3;1)
```

- if you are afraid of slowdown then import it into a new spreadsheet and then use `IMPORTRANGE` in the final spreadsheet to import it from "Google side"

Answer (score 0):

You can append the QUERY function to select only the Columns or Rows needed.

Comment: Using QUERY is similar to use INDEX; they increase formula complexity  and probably increase recalculation time.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTHTML` only imports complete lists or complete tables; it's not able to import only one element of the list either only one cell of the table.

One alternative is to use `IMPORTXML` but it only will work if your cell is part of a well-formed path (XPath)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to implement to your case:

```
=query({IMPORTHTML("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies","table")},"select Col1,Col2",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried with success:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films","table",1),,3)
```

The ,3 imports column 3 only add other column numbers with 1,2,3,4 etc.